# javascript node.js make a socket udp connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

coming from this page,
https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#class-dgramsocket
I took over this example:

```
const dgram = require('dgram');
const server = dgram.createSocket('udp4');

    server.on('error', (err) => {

  console.log(`server error:\n${err.stack}`);
  server.close();
});

server.on('message', (msg, rinfo) => {
  console.log(`server got: ${msg} from ${rinfo.address}:${rinfo.port}`);
});

server.on('listening', () => {
  const address = server.address();
  console.log(`server listening ${address.address}:${address.port}`);
});

server.bind(41234);
// Prints: server listening 0.0.0.0:41234
```

server.bind() would also work, then it takes a free port I guess.
But the example is not working , the clients response to 0.0.0.0 would not get received on this host.
So I chage to
server.bind(65000, "192.168.0.1");

But together with IP the interfaces forces me to specify a port. How can I omit this?

Thanks

Comment: And what do you want/is your question?

Comment: i want to automatically take a free port

Comment: Pass `null` or `undefined` as port.

Comment: but i need to specify an ip, and 
server.bind(undefined, ip); is not possible

Comment: It is possible, and it works. Its a common behaviour. Do: `server.bind(null, "172.16.0.18");` Update your question or specify what your want.

Comment: thats it, thanks!